# How to Access All HTTP Response Headers with same Title?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests, header

In python we can access a header of HTTP response like this:

```
response.headers['test']
```

But how can I access all headers with title = 'test'?

In some cases the server might do so in its response and I need to have access to all headers that share same title.

Comment: You can only possibly have one header with a unique name like 'test'. It will either exist or it won't. Unless you mean there may be multiple headers with the same prefix - e.g., test1, test2 etc. Or do you really mean headers with values equal to 'test'?

Comment: @DarkKnight according to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate#syntax that's not correct

Comment: For example, there might be multiple headers with the value `WWW-Authenticate` so how can I access all of them?

Comment: response.headers is of type requests.structures.CaseInsensitiveDict which, as far as I can tell, is just a subclass of dict and if that's the case I really don't know how you would achieve this. Also, I think that WWW-Authenticate cannot exist multiple times. There could be multiple challenges for one occurrence of that header name. I think you're misinterpreting the documentation

Comment: @DarkKnight the page I sent you shows you clear example, look for: '// Challenges specified in multiple headers'

Comment: Fair enough. Looks like a limitation of the requests module. You may need to use urllib module

Comment: See also  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie: _To send multiple cookies, multiple `Set-Cookie` headers should be sent in the same response._